# Vue Js should I be using Vuex for this?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am working through mini workshops for learning Vuejs. I have 2 components; PersonCard and ColorPick and a set of data. I can create a new person card for each person inside the person data, and in each person card I can create a colour picker (radio buttons) but I am stumped how to get the 'Picked Color' back to where the Person Card is rendered to be used as a style binding? I have been trying to use $emit but it doesn't work. Any advice would be welcomed.

I am pretty sure that I cannot grab and set updatedPlayers.color because updatedPlayers is an array that is iterated over in the template, but how do I target the specific 'player' in updatedPlayers to update their color based on the $emit?

App.vue

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <PersonCard :players="players"></PersonCard>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import PersonCard from './components/PersonCard.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      PersonCard
    },
    data () {
      return {
        players: [
        {
        id: 1,
        name: "Daniel",
        age: 33,
        color:"red"
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        name: "Sam",
        age: 21,
        color: "green"
        }
        ]
      }
    }

  };
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

PersonCard.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
      <li  v-for="player in updatedPlayers" :key="player.id">
          <h4 :style="{backgroundColor: player.color}">{{player.name}}</h4>
          <ColorPick @colorChosen="newColor"></ColorPick>
      </li>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import ColorPick from './ColorPick.vue'

export default {
data () {
    return {
        pickedColor: '',
        updatedPlayers : this.Players
    }
},
props: ['Players'],
components: {
    ColorPick
},
methods: {
    newColor (newColor) {
        this.updatedPlayers.color = newColor;
    }
}

};
</script>

<style scoped>
li {
    list-style: none !important;
}
</style>
```

ColorPick.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form action>
      <input type="radio" name="nameColor" value="yellow" v-model="pickedColor" @change="colorChosen" /> Yellow
      <br />
      <input type="radio" name="nameColor" value="red" v-model="pickedColor" @change="colorChosen" /> Red
      <br />
      <input type="radio" name="nameColor" value="blue" v-model="pickedColor" @change="colorChosen" /> Blue
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      pickedColor: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
      colorChosen(pickedColor) {
         this.$emit ('newColor', pickedColor);
      }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, if you have two components in a hierarchy then this doesn’t really need Vuex. You just need to think about your components and how they interact.

If a `PlayerCard` component has a child `ColorPicker` component, then you’re right that the `ColorPicker` component should emit an event with the picked colour. The `PlayerCard` component can just listen on that event and set whatever binding it needs to:

```html
<!-- /components/PlayerCard.vue -->
<template>
    <div v-bind:style="{ 'background-color': this.backgroundColor }">
        <color-picker v-bind:value="backgroundColor" v-on:input="updateBackgroundColor" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        components: {
            ColorPicker
        },
        data() {
            return {
                backgroundColor: '#000' // default
            };
        },
        methods: {
            updateBackgroundColor(event) {
                this.backgroundColor = event.target.value;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

```html
<!-- /components/ColorPicker.vue -->
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="color" v-on:input="onInput" v-bind:value="value" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            onInput(event) {
                this.$emit('input', event);
            }
        },
        props: {
            value: {
                required: true,
                type: String
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here we have two components. When the input in the `ColorPicker` changes its value, it passes the `input` event up to the `PlayerCard` component, that then sets the background colour in response.

The `ColorPicker` component also remains “dumb”, in that it doesn’t know anything about the components it’s being used in—it literally just allows a user to pick a colour. The parent component listens on the `input` event and does something in response. So this makes the `ColorPicker` component re-usable for picking other colours you may need to for your `PlayerCard` component, i.e. text colour.

There’s nothing here really that Vuex will solve that properly-written Vue components can’t accomplish. Vuex will just make it easier to code around problems, rather than solve any. But Vuex *does* have a place in larger applications.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your event listener is @colorChosen (in your PersonCard.vue), but you are emiting "newColor", change that to @newColor (in your PersonCard.vue). See if that helps.

`<ColorPick @newColor="newColor"></ColorPick>`

And yes Vuex can make passing bits of state from component to component a breeze. As your app grows and expands, it can get a little tricky to keep track of all your emits.